# Python script which takes arguments entered in a shell cames with an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, getopt

I am developing a script to automate mysql database and database' user creation. It takes arguments -o -dp -dr entered in a shell creates sql script with the following arguments (-o and -dp) and executes that script with a root password (-dr)

```
from sys import argv
from os import makedirs,system
etc = '/mnt/storage/'
def show_usage():
    print("""
        Create new DB and DB user
        -o object_name
        -dp db user password
        -dr mysql root user password
        """)
    exit(1)

def create_template(object_name, password):
    out = """
            %s template %s example %s %s %s %s
           """%(object_name,object_name,password,object_name,object_name)
    return out

def write_to_sql(object_name, db_password):
    sql_script = open(etc+'new_db_and_user.sql','w+')
    script_to_write = create_template(object_name,db_password)
    sql_script.write(script_to_write)

def execute_sql_script(root_password):
    run_sql_script = "mysql --username=root --password=%s < new_db_and_user.sql"%(root_password)
    remove_sql_script = "rm -f new_db_and_user.sql"
    system(run_sql_script)
    system(remove_sql_script)

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "hd:s:", ["object_name=","db_password=", "root_password="])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(str(err))

if opts.__len__() == 0:
    show_usage()

object_name=None
password=None
root_password=None

for option, value in opts:
    if option in ('-o', '--object_name'):
        object_name = value
    elif option in ('-dp', '--db_password'):
        password = value
    elif option in ('-dr', '--root_password'):
        root_password = value
    else:
        print("Unknown parameter used")
        show_usage()


write_to_sql(object_name,password)
execute_sql_script(root_password)
```

## Problem

When I execute this script with the following command

```
python create_db.py -o test -dp papa -dr nana
```

I get an error saying:

```
option -o not recognized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_db.py", line 43, in <module>
    if opts.__len__() == 0:
NameError: name 'opts' is not defined
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

When you got this in the output,

`option -o not recognized`

It means this line

`opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "hd:s:", ["object_name=","db_password=", "root_password="])`

has failed. So the execution falls through to the exception handler

```
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(str(err))
```

Therefore the variable `opts` is not created at all.

You can easily fix it by first define the variable before the `opts, args = ...` line. e.g.

```
try:
    opts = []  # Define the variable opts
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "hd:s:", ["object_name=","db_password=", "root_password="])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
    print(str(err))
```

Comment: tried your solution but it still gives an error saying -o is not recognized ```try:
 opts = []
 opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv[1:], "hd:s:",     ["object_name=","db_password=","root_password="])
except getopt.GetoptError as err:
 print(str(err)) ```

Comment: but it seems to work if i pass arguments in a long way like ```python create_db.py --object_name=test --db_password=papa --root_password=nana```

Comment: Because you did not have `o:` in `"hd:s:"`